# Open Chrome on other screen

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file

I have a bat file which launches Chrome with a simple command line like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --start-fullscreen -url http://google.com
```

My problem is that I have two screens and Chrome is opening on screen 2 and I want the bat file to ALWAYS open Chrome on screen 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1. Open Chrome (it will open on the screen where it was last closed)
2. Drag the Chrome window to screen 1
3. Close the chrome browser once it is on screen 1
4. Reopen the browser

Now it shall open on screen 1.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome lets pass windows position and size as arguments:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -url http://google.com --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1280,720
```

Window-Size should be set the to the resolution (sample 1280,720) of windows to make full screen like. Or you can use `--start-fullscreen`.